# How Search Popup component Communicate with two other components in angular

Tags: angular, search, popup

Search Project- I want to create a new search project in angular.

Requirement is that When i click on the search button in another site, it will navigate to searchcircular page in our project and show  a search popup from searchcircular page directly.
when i clicked on the search button ,it will show search results below that search button in popup.when i select a row from the search result and I need to hide this search popup and show details of this row to another page 'SearchDetails'.when we click on the search button in SearchDetails page ,again I have to show the same popup as we displayed earlier.

First I added a header and footer in appcomponent.
Then I created a search popup component and I included this in initial searchcircular page.

Then I created a SearchDetails component to show the details. and included search component here also.

My doubt is that how search popup component communicate with the searchcircular and SearchDetails components.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mat-dialog for pop-up, then you must be using something like this for popup:

```
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog){ }

const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(popUpComponent, {
  width: '40%'
});
```

Add this:

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
 // here you can get data from other component
});
```

And in your two other components, you would have used dialogRef.close(). Now, send some data for communication in close():

```
constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<searchCircularcomponent>){}

this.dialogRef.close('send your data here')
```